# Remove Specific Windows Shortcut to get Ahk shortcut to work

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, autohotkey, pycharm

I have a shortcut for brackets like "[]" and "()" that I use while coding which is written in .ahk

```
#d::
Send {[}{]}{Left}
return
```

It works fine, except in my Python editor Pycharm:
Somehow that when I use it there it activates a windows shortcut `Win+D` 
to show desktop and it jumps to the desktop.
I dont use the "show desktop" feature, so I would like that shortcut removed completely, without disabling other windows shortcuts like `Win+Right` ans so on.

[image]

EDIT (Partial Solution) :
as per Nelson's answer i have attempted to remove the `Send` in the ahk script
leading to this error [image]

Regarding pycharms keymaps, I have attempted to write a macro for square brackets in pycharm 
[image]

However, this is currently working now, i had forgotten to test the Pycharm Macro without the ahk script running.

But it still is not working, since in my other code editors (Rstudio) there are no macros, so now i have a shortcut that can only work in one program.

I'm still looking for a way to remove a specific Windows Shortcut.

Thanks for reading

Comment: I think I've seen a way to disable the native Windows hotkeys individually but am not finding it now.  This link shows how to disable all of them. http://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-disable-all-win-keyboard-shortcuts-hotkeys-in-windows/

Comment: You can use the `#IfWinActive` to enable that shortcut for your other editor.

Answer (score 1):

When you set this shortcut in AutoHotKey, it is suppose to override the default behavior.  Win+D key is a Windows shortcut key too.

You can test this by removing the `Send` line and see if the Win+D key does nothing in other applications.

However, PyCharm may have its own keyhook system and has a Win+D shortcut setup to replicate the function when the editor is active.  This is what's most likely causing the problem because it is capturing the keys before it reaches AutoHotKey.

PyCharm has instructions on how to [check and configure your keymaps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html#d1017597e151).

Comment: I'll upvote, for a helpful troubleshooting, but still doesn't provide any workaround or intended solution.

Comment: Can you host your entire AHK script somewhere if possible?  You're posting a tiny snippet, but you may have `#IfWinActive` or other odd keywords causing problems.  And my tip was suppose to be removing the whole line to test, not just the `Send` keyword.  You can comment out the line by adding a `;` at the start.

Comment: added entire script http://pastebin.com/8wP0QWdd , sorry it's quite long. 
Removing Send does not make the hotkey work in either code editors 
`#d::
;Send, {[}{]}{Left}
return`  Am i misunderstanding something?